# How to make exact values and match queries on same field in elasticsearch?

Tags: filter, elasticsearch

So I have a field that stores a value in the format: `number/year`, something like 23/2014, 24/2014, 12/2015, etc...

so if this field is mapped as a `not_analyzed` one, I can make exact value searches with term filter, if I search for a value in that exact structure(something like 1/2014, 15/2014,...) it works, like the `sql equals(=)`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "processNumber": "11/2014"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, searching with something different like 11/, or /2014 wouldn't return hits. This is fine.

But if I define the field as `not_analyzed`, I can't make `sql LIKE` type searches with the `match_phrase` query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "processNumber": "11/201"
    }
  }
}
```

In this case searching for 11,11/,/2014 or 2014 should return hits, but they don't.
The thing is, this query works if the field is not mapped as a `not_analyzed` one. So it seems I have to either use one or the other, the problem is that the field should support both options for different queries, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can analyze the same field *processNumber* in different ways using the  [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html#_multi_fields) property in the mapping:

For example if you want the analyzed and unanalyzed version of ProcessNumber the mapping would be :

```
 {
   "type_name": {
      "properties": {
         "processNumber": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "fields": {
               "analyzed": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Where the not-analyzed field is referred in query as ***processNumber*** .

To refer to the analyzed view of the field use ***processNumber.analyzed***

The queries for terms 11/201, 11 etc would be :

Example Filter:

```
 { "query" : { "filtered" : { "filter" : { "term" : { "processNumber" : "11/2014" } } } } }
```

Term filter it does not analyze the search string so an input would be matched as it is with the fields inverted index in this case : 11/2014 against the field.

Example Match_Phrase_prefix:

```
{ "query": { "match_phrase_prefix": { "processNumber": "11/201" } } }
```

[match_phrase_prefix](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix) tries to check if the last term in the phrase is a prefix of terms in index . 
It analyzes the search string if an analyzer is specified. This is the reason you need to use the *unanalyzed* version of the field here . If we use *processNumber.analyzed* search queries such as  **11-201 , 11|201** would also match

example match :

```
  { "query": { "match": { "processNumber.analyzed": "11" } } }
```

This is straight forward [match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query) since default analyzer (usually standard analyzer) will tokenize 11/2014 to  terms 11, 2014 .

You can use the analyze api to see how a particular text gets analyzed by default analyzer.

```
curl -XPOST "http://<machine>/_analyze?text=11/2014"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using the spring integration with elasticsearch and here's how the field is mapped currently:

@Field(type =   String,index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed) 
public String   processNumber;

I don't know if there's a way to set the fields property here.

Comment: Ok i think i got this to work:

@MultiField(
            mainField =@Field(type=String , index =FieldIndex.not_analyzed),
            otherFields = @NestedField(dotSuffix = "analyzed" , type = String,index=FieldIndex.analyzed)
    )
But can you tell me the difference between all three match queries?

Comment: @Maxrunner edited the answer to give a brief explanation of the queries.

Comment: Ony last quick question, while using the term filter against a field that has the string "Master", searching for "master" works, but not "Master", any reason?

Comment: Check your answer for my edit regarding the match_phrase_prefix.